# Sync Dropbox remotely

Tags: dropbox

I have Dropbox on my Ubuntu desktop, and I am working remotely on my laptop. I would like to add files from my desktop to Dropbox and then access them on my laptop.

So, I did the following:

```
ssh tomydesktop
ln -s myfile.txt ~/Dropbox/
```

and then when I

```
ls ~/Dropbox
```

`myfile.txt` shows up

However, myfile.txt does not show up either on the Dropbox website version of the folder or on my laptop.

Do I need to somehow "sync" the Dropbox folder from the desktop? I do not see any sync options on my laptop or on the website.

Comment: Generally, Dropbox monitors its directory and sync automatically after a change..

Comment: @SachinShekhar even if the user is logged out, the desktop is sleeping, or the screen is locked?

Comment: Hey, I assumed you've working Dropbox box in desktop.. Dropbox doesn't log out its users without demand.

Comment: There's no chance of sleeping desktop as you've SSHed it..

Comment: Yes, Dropbox does syncing even when screen is locked..

Comment: Is your server dropbox instance authenticated properly ? in this case my topic may help : https://superuser.com/questions/1312148/connect-remotely-to-dropbox-service-from-a-server?noredirect=1#comment1951488_1312148 hope this help.