# Connect remotely to Dropbox service from a server

Tags: linux, dropbox, authentication, daemon, headless

I wonder how to authenticate a remote linux server with dropbox daemon installed without X server.

Comment: Please follow the Q/A format of Stack Exchange. You can always answer your own question.

Comment: The above means: Please divide it into a question and its answer. Do not the answer inside the question.

Comment: ok this is noticed. I did not found it at edition time, beceause I posted it on stack overflow first and someone said me to post it there. The fact is that on  stack overflow it is possible to answer the question on the same page I edited it, and here, it is possible to do it after question is edited. The stack* websites are not consistant.

Comment: What's more the -1 downvote is not really appropriated for me as I understand upvotes and  downvote more on content quality / interest that on question form, and thus won't help reference "quality content" (this is a note beyond my post).

Answer (score 1):

My problem was : Connect a computer with dropbox installed to my account on a server where there is no graphical interface. This suppose you installed dropbox daemon from one of the many possible ways.

The fact is that I have a dropbox daemon running Dropbox status says 'Dropbox is running...' but I want my server to connect to my account.

The solution is to:

1) Stop the dropbox daemon dropbox stop

2) Start the daemon manually on the server `cd ~/.dropbox-dist/ && ./dropboxd`. This will start the dropbox daemon and display in the stdout an url on dropbox.com where as an authenticated user you can authorize the server to be connected.

That is all. This thread acts as a memo at least for me because I don't find easyly the solution each time I have to re-do this setup.

Then you have nothing else to do that run dropbox start again.